# How can I open the map in Skyrim using Papyrus or SKSE?

Tags: modding, skyrim-modding

While making a mod for Skyrim, I'd like to allow a player to chose a location to teleport to.

Essentially, I'll be:

- enabling Fast Travel if disabled
- changing fast travel speed so that the travel happens near instantly in game time
- opening the map to allow player to select destination
- resetting fast travel speed, disabling fast travel if appropriate

It's the third dot point I need help with. I can work out the others with Papyrus script, but is there a way to open the Map using Papyrus or SKSE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found the answer myself:

It can't be done with Papyrus, but can with SKSE using the Input function:

```
    int MapKey = Input.GetMappedKey("Quick Map")
    Input.TapKey(MapKey)
```

Needed to extract the SKSE script sources to Skyrim Data Script Source folder to get access to the SKSE functions.

Comment: Do you know if this works when the user is using an XBox 360 controller? I don't think that control scheme has a quick map button.